# Retrieve the ID column of a table when using Laravel Paginate

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following Laravel Fluent query to return paginated results from a Blog. I am trying to include the `id` column from the Posts table in the output but `$post->id` in the View returns the numeric key of that post in the paginated results. For example, if it is the third post the `$post->id` would return 3, even though the ID in the table would be something like 24.

Here is the query -

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('blog_categories', 'blog_categories.id', '=', 'posts.blog_category_id')
    ->order_by('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(10);
```

How can I retrieve the `id` column as something like `postID` without breaking the pagination?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both posts and blog_categories have their own id fields so it just defaults to the first record, usually just "1". I would look into using Eloquent ORM to solve this problem.

```
http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$posts = Post::order_by('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

And from the view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->id }}
    {{ $post->blog_cat->.... }}
@endforeach
```

I don't know the exact requirements of your project, but this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty sure this is the first thing I tried and ran into some sort of error, either way it's working fine.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version:

**Migration/Database**

```
    // Blog Categories
    Schema::create('categories', function($table) {

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';      
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->timestamps();   

    });

    // Posts
    Schema::create('posts', function($table) {

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title', 255);
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();   

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

    }); 

    // Fake Data
    $category = new Category;
    $category->name = 'Category 1';
    $category->save();

    $category = new Category;
    $category->name = 'Category 2';
    $category->save();      

    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = 'Blog Post 1';
    $post->body = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    $post->category_id = 2;
    $post->save();

    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = 'Blog Post 2';
    $post->body = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    $post->category_id = 1;
    $post->save();
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
    public function Category()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('Category','category_id');
    }               
}
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category extends Eloquent {   
}
```

**Getting data out...**

```
foreach (Post::with('Category')->order_by('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get() as $post)
{
    echo $post->title."<br/>";
    echo $post->body."<br/>";
    echo $post->category->name."<br/>";
    echo "<br/>\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to include pagination?

Comment: I included take(), which limits results. The take() and skip() methods are part of Fluent/Query Builder. More here: http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent#limit

You could just as easily use the paginate() option, since it's available to you as well. Read more here: http://laravel.com/docs/views/pagination#using-the-query-builder